# Simple "static" Ruby sites?

Tags: ruby, static

For early development, I typically build out a static version of the site. Previously I'd use PHP and have something like...

```
images
javascripts
stylesheets
templates
-- header.php
-- footer.php
index.php
users.php
```

And the `index.php` and `users.php` would have some basic PHP include code for those header and footer files.

I also got the added benefit of being able to use a few PHP functions.

But I haven't used PHP for anything in ages and use Ruby almost exclusively...so I'm wondering, is there a way to pull off something really basic like this in Ruby?

Primarily looking for something that allows me to:

1. Do basic file includes (so I can create simple templates)
2. Run Ruby inside the files

Ideally I could also use [LiveReload](http://livereload.com) with it.

Additional details: I'm running this locally on OS X and I typically use [Pow](http://pow.cx) as a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peter is right to recommend Sinatra. There are typically two types of Sinatra applications. Modular and classical. For your example, I'll create a classical application. It isn't much work to convert it to a modular if you find that style would better fit your needs.

You'll want to install the gem with `gem install sinatra`. Create a new directory for your project and two new files as follows:

```
# app.rb
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  erb :index
end

# config.ru
require './app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

Create another directory called views and add this file:

```
# index.erb
Hello World!
```

Then type ruby app.rb and viola, you now have a working project on `localhost:4567/`.
To serve static files like css and js, just create a public directory. From there, any file will be able to accessed after the root url. So if you created a css folder, its respective url would be: `yourdomain.com/css/styles.css`.

So the entire directory would be as folllows:

```
app/
  app.rb
  config.ru
  public/
    css/
    js/
    images/
  views/
    index.erb
```

Between the [Sinatra Book](http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/) and the [read me](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html), you should be able to find all the info you need.

To accomplish the templates, you'll need something called [Sinatra Partial](https://github.com/yb66/Sinatra-Partial).

I'm not too familiar LiveReload but it seems like [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) accomplishes the same thing and has great integration with Sinatra. So long as pow is a rack based, you should have no problem using it.

Here is a [Sinatra Bootstrap](https://github.com/whatasunnyday/sinatra-bootstrapkk) I use for all my projects. It has Compass and Sinatra Partial preconfigured and makes it really easy to deploy with Heroku. It also uses Slim, Coffeescript, Thin (as the server), Twitter Bootstrap and Sass but it shouldn't be too much work to sub that with your respective favorites or remove them all together.

Answer (score 1):

I gifted my girlfriend a website with her domain name, I chose Jekyll for the job which uses RubyGems for the purpose.

It was easy and fun. Moreover you have lots of themes available which you can configure with .YML files just changing there will work for hole site. Although Linux or Mac OS is suggested by official Jekyll website but i did it in windows which was not much of a problem. They have steps defined for working on windows on their website.

```
http://jekyllrb.com/
```

The best part was that i could host the website via the git hub pages only. I didn't have to buy anything. Git hub allows you to host one repo. (funFact : Jekyll was developed by github inventor)

That's the one i used and made the website in 20 hours with no prior knowledge of Ruby and Jekyll. 
So i will suggest you check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) will fit the bill?

Its description:

> Jekyll is a simple, blog aware, static site generator. It takes a
>   template directory (representing the raw form of a website), runs it
>   through Textile or Markdown and Liquid converters, and spits out a
>   complete, static website suitable for serving with Apache or your
>   favorite web server. This is also the engine behind GitHub Pages,
>   which you can use to host your project’s page or blog right here from
>   GitHub

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i use Sinatra for this, see https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/ for some samples.
Running ruby inside the files isn't very static but in Sinatra you can do both.

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll won't leave you run Ruby code "inside" the files. Jekyll is a parsing engine bundled as a ruby gem. You basically code templates using HTML and Liquid and write content using markdown that gets embebed generating plain HTML files that you can upload to any web server.